# How to get to the bottom of a JSON tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I come to you today with maybe a noob-ish question. I'm trying to parse a JSON response from the server on my client side but I seem to have hit a wall as I can't actually acces the data inside of it. Here's the JSON content I'm trying to go through. I just need the name as in   `name:"Topic3"`

```
'{
 links: [ ],
 content: [
    {
       links: [ ],
       content: {
          name: "Topic3",
          technology: {
             name: "Java",
             technology_id: 1
           },
           topic_id: 3
       },
   id: null
   },
   ],
   id: null
}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also this is my JS code that I tried to work on it with.

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "technologies/"+ option+ "/topics"
        }).then(function(data)
        {
            for(i=0;i<data.content.length;i++)
            {
                var topic = document.createElement("button");
                var content= (Object.keys(data.content[i]));
                topic.name= content.content.name;
                AddTopic.appendChild(topic);
            }
        });
```

Comment: try removing the second "content." from "content.content.name"

Comment: I've tried that and it makes the     topic.name= undefined

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It's already a javascript object, jquery converts it for you if you provide a `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: If I try using that Shubham I get a console error    Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: In that case, I would store `data` into a global variable an use the web developer to analyze it, do your test with this tool. You would be able to see the structure of you JSON and where is you problem (work with debugger too ;) )

Comment: The posted json string is invalid.

Comment: @DavidDomain, without the coma at the end of the content object, `data.content[0].content.name` works, so you should post your answer ;) I was working on this ... PS : Not sure if JQuery need the quotes for the identifier of each object

Comment: I would try console logging the values before actually trying to use them, e.g.

`            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
console.log(data[i].content.content.name)
            }`

Can you maybe show a response with two topics? Would help clear things up as not sure on the data structure

Answer (score 0):

To set button text use `innerHTML` property

```
            var topic = document.createElement("button");
            var content = data.content[i];
            topic.innerHTML = content.content.name;
            AddTopic.appendChild(topic);
```

Comment: That gives me an error " Cannot read property name of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you need to iterate through and find every available topic - in that case I believe this should work

```js
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "technologies/"+ option+ "/topics"
        }).then(function(data)
        {
            for(i of data.content)
            {
                var topic = document.createElement("button");
                topic.name= i.content.name;
                AddTopic.appendChild(topic);
            }
        });
```